# struts2 - how to efficiently accept a file uploaded in chunks, and maintain the chunk order

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, struts

A `C#` code is transmitting a large image file, breaking it into chunks, and it also sends the **chunk order** as a request parameter in each request. I wish to receive the file in a Struts2 action. Most examples I see, use `Apache Commons File Upload` to receive uploaded files, but its assumed that the files are transferred using `<http type="file"/>` as a multipart request. Even the streaming API assumes that.

Currently, I am thinking of storing each request's chunk in an array at the index received from the chunk **orderNumber** parameter. When all the chunks are received, I will write the file to the system. But it has some problems. I will have to maintain the state of the array across multiple requests, and action classes are `stateless`. Also, how will I find that the particular chunk is the last ? (I can send a request parameter with the last chunk, but if there's any other cleaner way)

Edit - image types can differ, the EOF marker is always a constant query string parameter, the image is always broken into constant-sized chunks (the buffer is 1024 bytes, can be changed) except the last one. The C# program can be altered. The user using the C# code would be already signed in, and there can be concurrent transfer of different files. After-crash-resume is not required.

Actually, the C# program is just a `Silverlight` plugin that is there to facilitate **drag n  drop** of files, and send them to the server (**only for IE**, as IE doesn't support drag n drop of files)

Comment: The understanding between sender and receiver seem to be not well defined. Is the image type always the same, and is there constant EOF marker? Is the image broken into constant sized blocks, and only the last one could be a different size? Can you alter the C# program? Can the sending program can it sign on to your system and maintain a session? Are there likely to be concurrent transfers of different files? Do you need to be able to resume if the system crashes?

Comment: Added the clarifications to the question. Kindly see